# for loop exit if condition is not met

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, indexing, enumerate

I am trying to write a Shiritori game in Python. In the game you are given a word (ex: dog) and you must to add another word that starts with the end of the previous word ex(: doG, Goose).
So given a list words = ['dog', 'goose', "elephant"  'tiger', 'rhino', 'orc', 'cat'] it must return all value, but if "elephant" is missing it must return:
["dog","goose"] because "dog" and "goose" match, but "goose" and "tiger" not.

I am running into a bug where it either loop out of range checking next index in list or it returns only "dog" and not "goose", or it returns ["dog","goose"] and than exit the loop without iterating through the rest of the list(s).
What am I doing wrong?

```
def(game():
words = ['dog', 'goose', 'tiger', 'rhino', 'orc', 'cat']
check_words = ['goose', 'tiger', 'rhino', 'orc', 'cat']
# check words has one less element to avoid index out or range in the for loop
# example = if word[-1] != words[index+1][0]: # index+1 gives error
good_words = []
for index, word in enumerate(words):
    for index2, word2 in enumerate(check_words):
        # I want to add the correct pair and keep looping if True
        if word[-1] == word2[0]:
            good_words.extend([word,word2])
    return good_words # break out of the loop ONLY when this condition is not met
print(game())
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you needed the 2nd for loop.

here is a solution.

```
def game():
    words = ['dog', 'goose', 'elephant',  'utiger', 'rhino', 'orc', 'cat']
    good_words = []
    for index in range(0, len(words)):
        if index+1 < len(words):
            previous_word = words[index][-1]
            next_word = words[index+1][0]
            if previous_word == next_word:
                # appends the new word if not in list
                if words[index] in good_words:
                    good_words.append(words[index+1])
                else:
                    # only used for the first time to append the current and the next word
                    good_words.append(words[index])
                    good_words.append(words[index+1])
        else:
            return good_words # break out of the loop ONLY when this condition is not met
    return good_words
print(game())
```

Answer (score 0):

your code need an indent after "def game():".